# Android Room OnCreate Callback isn't being called on emulator

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-asynctask, android-room

I'm trying to initialize my android room database. I try to call the userDAO in an asyncTask to initiate the onCreate callback for the first run. The onCreate callback is going to pre populate my database. It returns a null pointer.
I'm not sure if it has something to do with asyncTask calling another asynctask and it finishing before the database is pre populated or if I'm using the callback incorrectly. Thanks in advance for any feedback!

this is the database file

```
    @Database(entities = {UserDB.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
    public abstract class RoomDatabase extends androidx.room.RoomDatabase {

    //create the name for the database and create an empty instance
    private static final String DB_NAME = "person_DB";
    private static RoomDatabase instance;
    //create connection to the DAO for personal database
    public abstract UserDAO userDAO();
    public static RoomDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        return instance;
    }
    //when called, check for instance of database, but if not there, create an instance with context, database, and name of db
    public static RoomDatabase getDbInstance(Context context) {
        if(instance == null) {
            synchronized (RoomDatabase.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), RoomDatabase.class, DB_NAME)
                            .addCallback(rdc)
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("returning instance of db");
        return instance;
    }

    //Create a callback to populate the database with the users profile information
    private static RoomDatabase.Callback rdc = new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
        //make method for creating first database outline
        @Override
        public void onCreate (SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onCreate(db);
            System.out.println("entering onCreate");
            new PopulateDbAsyncCreate(instance).execute();
        }
       public void onOpen (SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
           //empty for now
       }
    };

    }

this is the pre populate file

    class PopulateDbAsyncCreate extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void> {
    //member variable for getting user dao
    private final UserDAO mUserDAO;

    //get the DAO on construction to edit db with
    public PopulateDbAsyncCreate(RoomDatabase mdb) {
        mUserDAO = mdb.userDAO();
    }
    //in background remove all data inside user-profile and replace with empty inserted
     @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {
        if(mUserDAO.getAnyUser().getFirstName().isEmpty()) {
            mUserDAO.deleteAll();
            UserDB user = new UserDB("new", null, null, 0, 0,
                    0, 0, 0);
            mUserDAO.insert(user);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

finally this is my main function

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public RoomDatabase mdb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //create instance of DB IDK if I need to change this to getting an instance of DB
        mdb = RoomDatabase.getDbInstance(this);
        //check database to see if it is empty using asyncTASK
        CheckDB check = new CheckDB(mdb);
        check.execute();

        //set button listener to go to home page
        final Button button;
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            goToCreateUser();
            }
        });
    }

    //method for going to createUser Screen
    private void goToCreateUser() {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateUser.class));
        this.finish();
    }

    //method for going to home screen after button press and finishing this current activity
    private void goToHomeScreen() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, home.class));
        this.finish();
    }


    //inner class for checking if database exists
    public class CheckDB extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
        //init member of db
        private RoomDatabase mdb;

        //constructor for setting db member to current db of app
        public CheckDB(RoomDatabase mdb) {
            this.mdb = mdb;
        }

        //on execute it checks to see if any user exists and returns null if they do exist
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            UserDAO userDAO = mdb.userDAO();
            final String name = userDAO.getAnyUser().getFirstName();
            if(name.equals("new") || name.isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }
            return "GoodTOGO";
        }

        //receives output of doInBackground and performs screen change if the user's profile already
        //exists
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String input) {
            String s = input;
            if(s != null) {
                goToHomeScreen();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: remove this line from code "public static RoomDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
    return instance;
}".

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't fix the error I'm getting. I still receive the null pointer. I guess that line is redundant though right?

Comment: For me it's calls with no table and no version!